# Django1.6 transaction.atomic questions

Tags: django, transactions, postgresql-9.1, atomic, django-1.6

I just switched to Django 1.6 (with Posgres 9.1) and there is a few questions that I couldn't answer myself:

1. *(Answered) Is there a statement that prints/shows me if I am currently inside one or more and in which `transaction.atomic` blocks?*
2. *(Answered) I neither have `TransactionMiddleware` enabled nor set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` to True. So per default my code is not wrapped inside a `transaction.atomic` block, correct?*
3. Are sql statements that are executed via cursor committed properly when executed inside a `transaction.atomic` block? Is there another/better way to commit them?

   ```
   with transaction.atomic():
       cursor = connection.cursor()
       cursor.execute(sql)
   ```
4. Do I need to wrap `cursor.executemany()` in a `transaction.atomic` block or does the execution already happen atomically?
5. How can I see the current `autocommit` status? When is the status set, at the beginning of a connection, a transaction, as global database setting?

Comment: #2 is definitely true... the default behavior has been changed to DB-level autocommit

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 3):

To answer one of your questions:

You can find out if you are currently in an atomic block using the `connection` object returned from:

`from django.db.transaction import get_connection` or any of the connection objects inside of `django.db.connections`

which has an `in_atomic_block` property.

---

I feel like its going to be easiest just to look through the [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/transaction.py)

Comment: `django.db.transaction.get_connection()` is "a private API" according to its docstring. I think you should use `from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS; connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS].in_atomic_block` instead.